# Best practices for keeping user data in sync between tabs/browsers/locations? (Avoiding one tab overwriting another)

Tags: reactjs, websocket

I'm currently building a web app using a typical MERN stack. The primary function of the app is to serve as a somewhat complex table/spreadsheet. Right now, when someone updates their table in the browser, it sends the updates to the server, which saves it to the database, pretty simple, this has been working fine for the month we've been in beta with ~600 users.

However, I just got a contact from a user saying their table keeps getting deleted/emptied out. They really didn't give me any other information, but the only thing I can think of is that they may have two tabs or browsers open.

I tested it myself, and if I create an empty table and then open it in two tabs and I add 20 rows to one table, then refresh the page, it persists. If I then go to the other tab, the table is still obviously empty because I'm not using websockets or anything to poll for changes. Then if I add 1 row and update the table. Then refresh, the table now has one row in it. Go back to the other tab, refresh, 1 row.

I believe this is what's occurring for the user. I realize I can just set up websockets and listen for changes, then update, but that seems like a large lift and could introduce its own set of issues.

Is there an easier, more standard approach I'm missing other than introducing a websocket, or is this a problem that most apps just dont bother to solve?